# Cannot acces subfolder files and mysql database after switching server to Parallel Panel

Tags: mysql, file, panel, subdirectory, parallels

Recently my domains server was switched to parallel panel. Now I'm not able to access my subfolder files, i. e. `abc_folder/index.php`.

It's showing HTTP error 404. In physical path it's showing `D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\trytest.com\httpdocs\abc_folder\index.php`.

I tried to follow [these instructions](http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/478/Setting-file-folder-permissions-from-Plesk-control-panel-for-Windows.html) but still got the same error.

Even am not able to access mysql database :
I tried to access my file within the same directory

```
<?php

/*online*/
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="trytest_abc"; // Mysql username
$password="nTnb1%31"; // Mysql password
$db_name="trytest_pqr"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");  
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
//echo 'Connection to localhost successful';

?>
```

When i did so the error am getting is:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'trytest_abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\trytest.com\httpdocs\connection.php on line 10 cannot connect
```

Comment: This question doesn't belong on SO. It's a Super User (or maybe even a software-specific) question.

Comment: While you're at it, replace the deprecated `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: What's the filename of the code you posted? Since it doesn't have `Line 17` and is trying to access your DB with username `trytest`, though in your posted code username is `trytest_abc`.